# returning an array of n numbers repeated into another array

Tags: java, arrays

Basically i have to return an array of n numbers repeated in an array into another array of length m.
my code so far:

```
public class Histogram {
     public static int[] frequency(int[] a, int M) {
         int[] m = new int[M];
         int count = 0;
         for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
             if( i == a[j]){
                m[i] = count++;
             }
      }
      return m; 
} public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 11, 11, 1, 5, 8, 4, 2, 9, 4, 3, 9,
               2, 10, 11, 7, 7, 1, 11, 3, 8, 8, 10, 4, 10, 5};
    int[] b = frequency(a, 12);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        Std.Out.println(i + "->" + b[i]);
     }   } }
```

this is the output im supposed to get

```
0->0
1->3
2->2
3->2
4->4
5->2
6->0
7->3
8->3
9->3
10->4
11->4
```

but im getting

```
0->0
1->21
2->16
3->23
4->27
5->29
6->0
7->20
8->25
9->15
10->28
11->22
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to give you a different solution, but rather to show the mistakes in your code. If we go with the logic in your code, you have few mistakes:

1) count should be reset to 0 after first loop. Otherwise you will sum up the counts from the previous iterations.

2) count++ should be before the assignment, otherwise it will first assign and then increment. Or you could use ++count.

3) The first loop should be over i.

```
public static int[] frequency(int[] a, int M) {
     int[] m = new int[M];
     int count;
     for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
     count =0;
     for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         if( i == a[j]){
            count++;
            m[i] = count;
         }
     }

    return m;

  }
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistakes, it makes more sense to me seeing what i missed instead of just taking someone elses code. Anyways i'd upvote you but i literally just made an account and still fairly new at coding. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it and do the job!

```
public class Histogram {

    public static int[] frequency(int[] a, int M) {
        int[] m = new int[M];
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            m[a[j]] += 1;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 11, 11, 1, 5, 8, 4, 2, 9, 4, 3, 9, 
                2, 10, 11, 7, 7, 1, 11, 3, 8, 8, 10, 4, 10, 5};
        int[] b = frequency(a, 12);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "->" + b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Histogram {
     public static int[] frequency(int[] a, int M) {
         int[] m = new int[M];
         for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) //loop through a
            if( i < M) //number check
                m[a[i]]++; //add one to m at index a[i]
         return m;    
      }
}
```

this is the right code for the method frequency, also checks to see if the number is in range.